# Installing add-on in Firefox 22+ globally on OS X

Tags: macos, firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

How do I install an add-on globally in Firefox 22+ on Mac OSX? There have been so many changes to the add-on API and directory structures in the past year nothing I have found seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach?

To install an extension to be used by all users on Mac OS X, copy it to:

> /Library/Application Support//Extensions//

For example, if you've created a standalone application for Mac OS X that includes a plugin for Firefox, your installer would extract its extensions files to the following folder:

> /Library/Application
> Support/Mozilla/Extensions/{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}/{dba45d40-f69e-11dc-95ff-0800200c9a66}

Where `{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}` is Firefox's application ID,

and `{dba45d40-f69e-11dc-95ff-0800200c9a66}` is the extension's ID.

Source : [Installing extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Installing_extensions#Mac_OS_X)